# Почему typeof "4px" - 2 возвращает NaN?

Tags: javascript

Со скобками `typeof ("4px" - 2)` возвращает `number`. Это понятно, поскольку `typeof NaN` это `number`. Непонятно, почему при отсутствии скобок (то есть `typeof "4px - 2"`) результат `NaN`?

Comment: потому что без скобок отнимается двойка а не учитывается

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Здесь все дело в порядке выполнения. У арифметических операторов приоритет ниже, чем у оператора `typeof`.

Поэтому если скобки не ставить, то компилятор неявно преобразует выражение к такому виду:

```
(typeof "4px") - 2;
```

Что аналогично следующему:

```
"string" - 2;
```

А при вычитании числа из строки результат всегда `NaN` (за исключением тех случаев, когда строка содержит нечто, что является числом с точки зрения языка. Например - `"2"`, `"Infinity"`, `"-Infinity"` и т.д.).

Comment: _при вычитании числа из строки результат всегда NaN_ - не всегда. Например: `'5' - 2` -> 3

Comment: @Grundy из строки в привычном понимании, разумеется. А не числа в виде строки. Да, пожалуй, стоит поправить формулировку.

Comment: Точно, теперь понял, А вот тут что произошло? (parseInt(null, 24) === 23) каким образом преобразованные в число NaN и 24 трансформировались в 23?

Comment: @HovhannesShaxulyan а, ну в общем-то тут все понятно. Задавайте вопрос - получите ответ.

Comment: – smellyshovel я у вас спрашивал, просто  пока не вдавался в подробности, как добавить имя в вопрос....... Можете ответить почему (parseInt(null, 24) === 23)?  Каким образом преобразованные в число NaN и 24 трансформировались в 23?

Comment: @HovhannesShaxulyan нельзя так делать. Задайте **отдельный**, новый вопрос, в котором спросите об этом. Не стоит задавать несколько вопросов в одном. Тем более, в комментариях. Задайте новый вопрос - там я вам и отвечу.